# When can an SQL result contain duplicates?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I'm just learning about relational databases and was told they don't allow duplicate entries. I did not believe this at first because I wrote SQL queries which returned results with duplicates. It's that the system doesn't store sets that are identical in one relation right? I mean if you had a relation for books and authors and chosed only to select authors then it may appear that there are duplicates if the same author had written different books (e.g. `select author from Books`). Also if you use join then you can get duplicate results, right? Any other scenarios?

Basically when people say rmdbs don't have duplicates they just mean the way the information is stored (in one table) right?

Comment: "and was told they don't allow duplicate entries" - you probably mis-understood or missed some of the context.

Comment: @Mat I'm sure I misunderstood hence why I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: This is not clear. What does "the way the information is stored (in one table)" mean? Or "sets [rows? subrows?] that are identical in one relation"? What are "duplicate entries"?--duplicate rows? Or "duplicate results"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relational databases consist only of relation variables (relational "tables") which by definition always consist of unique tuples ("rows"). A relational database management system uses a query language based on Codd's relational algebra which similarly can't generate duplicates in results because every result in relational algebra is also a relation and therefore consists of unique tuples.

Your confusion arises because you are assuming that SQL is a proper relational language and SQL DBMSs are relational. It isn't and they aren't. Things get tricky when you start to compare SQL with its near-equivalents in the relational world. Your SQL query:

```
SELECT author FROM Books;
```

may return duplicate rows, but the apparently similar relational query:

```
π author (Books)
```

will not. The relational query is more like the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT author FROM Books;
```

You have to be extremely careful in SQL to avoid getting duplicates where you don't want or expect them. It's a problem that trips up even experienced SQL users.

Answer (score 6):

Relations are sets of tuples.  Because they are sets, relations cannot contain the same tuple twice.

If something (e.g. a "table" in SQL) does contain "the same tuple twice", then that thing is not a relation, and the language is not a relational language.  At best, the language could be used in a relational fashion if (and only if) the language user imposes the necessary self-discipline upon himself.

Brief : relational DBMS's indeed cannot allow duplicates, and typical SQL engines are not relational DBMS's for exactly this reason (a.o.)

Answer (score 1):

You can very well put duplicates in a table, unless there is a constraint for the table that specifically disallows it.

Often a table has a primary key, and a primary key is a constraint that disallows duplicates for the fields that is part of the key, so that would keep the table from having duplicate records.

Comment: But isn't that primary key sort of artifical in the senese it's an attribute there just for that purpose? I mean if you query `insert x into y` twice where y has just one attribute what would happen?

Comment: If there's a unique constraint *(or primary key)* on the column(s) for that table the RDBMS will not allow the second insert but it's up to the databasedesigner to tell the RDBMS what columns in what tables should be unique. No RDBMS *(that I know of)* enforces this uniqueness by default.

Comment: You can put duplicates in a TABLE, but the question is about how that matches to relational theory saying RELATIONS cannot have duplicates.  This is not an answer to that question.

Comment: That's what downvoting is for.  Marking poor answers.  Poor answers don't get better by time passing.

Answer (score -1):

RDBMS can have duplicates especially if they are not setup very well. Setting up a RDBMS requires you to understand what Normalization is. If you are having duplicates, it means your tables are probably not in 1st Normalization form. The definition of a table in 1st Normalization Form is the eradication or elimination of repeating values, so if you are having repeating/ duplicate values, you need to bring your table to a 1st Normalization Form standard first by eliminating repeating values, then to its 2nd Normalization Form, and so on.

Comment: The question makes it sufficiently clear that the question is about duplicate ROWS inside TABLES.  This is nowhere near an answer to that question.